# Why are some key inputs not working in this exemple ? (pygame)

Tags: python, input, pygame, keyboard-events

Im making a small game with pygame just to train using it and I encountered this problem.

```
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:

        running = False

    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:


        if event.key==pygame.K_z:

            print('test')
            Player.existing[0].Jump()

        if event.key==pygame.K_UP:

            Player.existing[1].Jump()

        if event.key==pygame.K_q:

            print('yes')
            Player.existing[0].RunningLeft  = True

        if event.key==pygame.K_d:

            print('no')
            Player.existing[0].RunningRight = True
```

(This is not the whole code but the only part that matters)

When I press d, it works and 'no' gets printed but with any other key nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code exactly (I just added the extra code needed for it to run like the pygame import and the pygame.init()) and it seems to work fine.

Make sure that whenever you're pressing a key your Pygame window is selected otherwise, it won't be recognized.